# App built with Qt 4.7 - how to listen to applescript commands?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, applescript

**Test environment:** macOS 10.12.6
**Build system:** Qt 4.7 (required for backwards compatibility)

I have an application, **SdrDx**, I build with Qt 4.7; I want to tell the application to move the main window to near the top left. It's running under macOS 10.12.6.

Here's what I've tried, which works with Finder (replace SdrDx with "Finder" and the Finder window moves):

```
tell application "SdrDx"
    activate
    set position of window 1 to {10, 10}
end tell
```

When this script is run, Apple's script editor returns:

```
error "SdrDx got an error:
Can’t set position of window 1 to {10, 10}."
number -10006 from position of window 1
```

The `activate` works: the SdrDx window activates. So I know I'm at least basically talking to the right application. There's only one window; I read that the main window isn't always the "actual" window, so I've tried window numbers from 1 to 10, but all those values produce the same error.

How do I catch this message, or otherwise enable my app to deal with it? I know how to move the window from *inside* the application, it seems like I need to know what the Applescript catch mechanism is so I can invoke that kind of code?

Comment: The application must have an AppleScript dictionary to respond to AppleScript commands. Drag the application onto the icon of Script Editor. You will get a message if the target app is not scriptable.

Comment: I already know it's not scriptable, and yes, following your steps tells me that. And as I understand it, the dictionary tells the script editor what commands are available. It doesn't make the app understand them. What I'm looking for is how to make the app understand the issued commands. Am I going about this wrong?

Comment: *The dictionary tells the editor what commands are available*, right. And it **does** make the app understand them. You have to add an AppleScript dictionary to your app, but achieving this is not trivial.

Comment: okay, I'll chase that a bit. Thank you. Will be back clicking upmods if it pans out. :)